# Blazor Server + Azure B2C Identity - Change Cookie Name

Tags: cookies, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, blazor

When creating a stock Blazor Server app (File/New) with Authentication for B2C you get a `Startup.cs` that looks like the following.

B2C itself is working, but I'm trying to simply change the Cookie name. By default it appears to be (`.AspNetCore.AzureADB2CCookie`)

How can I change it?

I've tried the following which doesn't appear to work:

1)

```
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = UIConstants.WebSessionCookieName;
        });
```

2)

```
        .AddCookie(x =>
        {
            x.Cookie.Name = UIConstants.WebSessionCookieName;
        });
```

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
            AzureADB2CDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = UIConstants.WebSessionCookieName;
            });
```

Comment: B2c sets session cookie, I tried to set ExpireTimeSpan to make it persistant. but it doesn't seems to work.